# Implement Guava cache as a fallback for EHCache

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, caching, guava, ehcache

I want to implement Guava cache in my springboot application as a fallback for EHcache 2.10. If EH cache somehow fails or crashes, the system must fallback to Guava cache and get the result. Please guide me how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario ** built-in** annotation can be used so you can check and build all logics on your own.

You can always define DAO(Data Access Object) layer, this will communicate with EHCahe and Guava cache.

```
interface UserDao{
   Optional<User> findById(int id);
   ...
}
```

Implements UserDao

```
class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowired  @Qualifier("ehCacheManager") private CacheManager ehCacheManager;
    @Autowired  @Qualifier("cacheManager") private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Autowired  UserRepository userRepository;
    private Cache ehCache;
    private Cache guavaCache;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ehCache = ehCacheManager.get("userCache");
        guavaCache = cacheManager.get("userCache");
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(int id){
         User user = null;
         boolean ehCacheError;
         try{
            user = ehCache.get(id, User.class);
         } catch (Exception e){
             user = guavaCache.get(id, User.class);
             ehCacheError = true;
         }
         if( user == null ){
          // query db to fetch User as all cache has miss
           Optional<User> optUser = userRepository.findById( id );
           if(optUser. isPresent()){
              user = optUser.get();
           }
           // cache miss
           if(!ehCacheError){
               ehCache.put( id, user) ;
               guavaCache.put(id, user);
           }
         }
         return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
    
}
```

One surprising question, why do you reverse wise, you should always perform Guava cache lookup, if there's a cache miss, you should consult EHCache, here you should add a fail case to query db.